# How to fetch row count in PHP in Mysql Database?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$count = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users");

echo $count;
```

This is not working . Error message Resource id Unknown #21.
how to fix this ?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Try this: var_dump($count). Maybe it helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use [`fetchColumn()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php)

```
$count = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users");
```

Should be

```
$count = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users")->fetchColumn();

echo $count; //Returns number of rows
```

Comment: i am not using PDO. Msql connection is used.

Answer (score -1):

use this mysql_num_rows

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users");
$count= mysql_num_rows($sql);
echo $count ;
```

Comment: This answer is wrong as it will return 1 every time it is called