# PHP counter increment in a while loop

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, counter

Im having a problem incrementing a counter in one of my while loops basically i just want to alternate between two image links that were fetched in my database but my counter wont increase and im not sure why can anyone help?

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      $img_link = $row['Image'];
      $img_link_alt = $row['Image_alt'];
      $i = 0;

       echo '<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">'; 
       $img = ( $i % 2 == 0 ) ?  $img_link : $img_link_alt; 

            echo $i;
            //'?' . date("h:i:sa").'
            echo '<img style="height:200px; border-radius:0%; width:300px;" src="screenshots/'. $img . '">';          
            echo '<h4>Screenshot</h4><span class="text-muted">Updated Screenshot of the Botting session: <b>' . $row['script_name'] .' </b></span>'; 
            echo '</div>';        
            $i++;        
        }
```

Ive even tried declaring $i outside of the while loop and still nothing..... any help would be much appreciated

Comment: You are resetting it to 0 in each loop.... (  $i = 0;)

Comment: Delete $i = 0; in the while loop. Just above while ($row...), put $i = 0; Try another option. Instead of incrementing and then finding $i % 2, just do $i = ($i === 0) ? 1 : 0; That way, each time you go in the loop, $i will change.

Comment: "Ive even tried declaring $i outside of the while loop and still nothing..... any help would be much appreciated"  sorry guys i tried it outside the while loop and still nothing....

Comment: try also to print the condition in your while loop it might help you...

Answer (score 1):

Initialize $i outside the loop.

```
$i = 0;
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      $img_link = $row['Image'];
      $img_link_alt = $row['Image_alt'];

       echo '<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">'; 
       $img = ( $i % 2 == 0 ) ?  $img_link : $img_link_alt; 

            echo $i;
            //'?' . date("h:i:sa").'
            echo '<img style="height:200px; border-radius:0%; width:300px;" src="screenshots/'. $img . '">';          
            echo '<h4>Screenshot</h4><span class="text-muted">Updated Screenshot of the Botting session: <b>' . $row['script_name'] .' </b></span>'; 
            echo '</div>';        
            $i++;        
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

move the

```
$i
```

initialization:

```
 $i=0
```

outside of the while loop and it worked. you every time renizialize the

```
$i
```

variable in your while loop,and your counter don't increase, fix it.
An alternative is use the rows counter, like that example:

```
$count = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users")->fetchColumn();

echo $count; //Returns number of rows
```

like in that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21481038/php-fetch-row-count)

Answer (score 0):

You have to reset $i outside the loop:

```
$i = 0;
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $img_link = $row['Image'];
  $img_link_alt = $row['Image_alt'];
   echo '<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">'; 
   $img = ( $i % 2 == 0 ) ?  $img_link : $img_link_alt; 
       echo $i;
        //'?' . date("h:i:sa").'
        echo '<img style="height:200px; border-radius:0%; width:300px;" src="screenshots/'. $img . '">';          
        echo '<h4>Screenshot</h4><span class="text-muted">Updated Screenshot of the Botting session: <b>' . $row['script_name'] .' </b></span>'; 
        echo '</div>';        
        $i++;        
}
```

Comment: Ive even tried declaring $i outside of the while loop and still nothing..... any help would be much appreciated" sorry guys i tried it outside the while loop and still nothing....

Comment: try to print $row to see if there is actual result. I would print $i, to know if this loop iterates over a data. Try to put print_r($row); inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

Put the `$i` variable outside the `while` block, like this:

```
$i = 0;

while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      $img_link = $row['Image'];
      $img_link_alt = $row['Image_alt'];

       echo '<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">'; 
       $img = ( $i % 2 == 0 ) ?  $img_link : $img_link_alt; 

            echo $i;
            //'?' . date("h:i:sa").'
            echo '<img style="height:200px; border-radius:0%; width:300px;" src="screenshots/'. $img . '">';          
            echo '<h4>Screenshot</h4><span class="text-muted">Updated Screenshot of the Botting session: <b>' . $row['script_name'] .' </b></span>'; 
            echo '</div>';        
            $i++;        
        }
```

Comment: Ive even tried declaring $i outside of the while loop and still nothing..... any help would be much appreciated" sorry guys i tried it outside the while loop and still nothing....

Answer (score 0):

```
$i  = 0;
while($i<5) {
    $alternateVal   = $i%2==0 ? "type1" : "type2";
    echo $alternateVal;
    $i++;
}
```

Above is an example to overview alternate values.